# Drupal 7 get node id in AJAX

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-ajax

i'm submitting a form to create node using ajax. I can able to create a node using `drupal_get_form('node_form', $node)` but i need the node id in response. Can anyone help me out to get the node id in ajax response after creating the node.

Comment: make your context a bit clear

Comment: @mohanraj If I got what you mean you want to get nid in $.ajax() ?

Comment: No, i mean to use get the value from system/ajax where my input will be content type form

Answer (score 2):

Or you can add the hidden field to the form like this:

```
$form['hidden-nid'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'hidden',  
    '#value' => menu_get_object()->nid,
);
```

and get the value in ajax function:

```
$id = intval($form_state['input']['hidden-nid']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the node_form function, do something like this,

```
$node = menu_get_object();
$node_id = $node->nid;
$form_state['#id'] = $node_id;
```

In the callback function you can get it as,

```
$id = $form_state['id'];
```